# why use each when creating a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

Im a bit confused with the use of each when creating plugins.  Ive created a simple plugin with a callback as a test.

```
<div>Click me 1</div>
<div>Click me 2</div>
```

Without each :-

```
(function($){    
    $.fn.TestCallBack = function(options){
        var defaults = {
            onClicked :function(){}
        }

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

        function DoSomething(){
            settings.onClicked.call(this);    
        }

        $(this).bind("click", DoSomething);     

        return this;
}
})(jQuery);

$("div").TestCallBack({onClicked:function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
}});
```

This produces the results

```
Click me 1
Click me 2
```

With each :-

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.TestCallBack = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            onClicked: function () {}
        }

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        function DoSomething() {
            settings.onClicked.call(this);
        }

        this.each(function(){
            $(this).bind("click", DoSomething);
        });        

        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);

$("div").TestCallBack({
    onClicked: function () {
        console.log($(this).html());
    }
});
```

this produces the results

```
Click me 1
Click me 2
```

i thought using each would iterate over the divs found but why does the code not using each provide the same results.  Im obviosuly missing something here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you do to `this` is calling jQuery's `bind` on it.
This internally does that operation for all elements of the set `this`.

You would need to iterate over all elements with `each` when doing something with them that is not automatically applied to all items of the set.

Comment: thanks.  Can you give examples of things that are not automatically applied to all the elements?

Comment: jQuery's operations are quite consistent with applying them to the whole set of elements. but imagine, you would want to do something based on a condition like this: `if (this.hasClass('test'))`
this would not work when just treating the set as a whole, you would have to check for every item in the set if it has the class.

Answer (score 0):

You use `each` to be able to follow jQuery convention of returning the original set of jQuery objects, which in turn enables chaining.

The way you are using `each` doesn't make it. It should be used like this:

```
 $.fn.extend({
        TestCallBack : function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                // write your code here
            });
        }
});
```

Now you can code like this:

```
$('div').TestCallBack().stop().show(). .....
```

Without `each` returning, you will not be able to chain further jQuery methods on the original set.

More information here: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Scroll down on that page to the section: "*Using the each() Method*"

Comment: your main point is about returning the original set to allow `method chaining`. this is not OP's main concern. Your reference to the documentation is a good starting point though.

Comment: I thought the Op's question was as mentioned in the title of the question: "*why use each when creating a jquery plugin*", so I explained the use of `each` and why it isn't applying to his scenario.

Comment: Yes, but your main point is method chaining. To achieve that, you could also just do a `return this;` when finished with your operations - no each involved. The real point behind using `each` is to loop through all elements of the set and do your plugin operations to all of them, as it is a very common jQuery approach to deal with sets of elements (i.e. selecting them by a `css class`.

Comment: @Chips_100 I agree to you fully. You had already answered that part, so I decided not to repeat it and just link to the documentation where it says "*If you want to do any manipulating with specific elements...*". Instead, I pointed out that returning on each as a method wrapper is preferable. This is also mentioned in the reference: "*Notice that we return the results of .each() instead of returning this. Since .each() is already chainable, it returns this, which we then return. This is a better way to maintain chainability than what we've been doing so far.*"